# Are the values of Shared Properties outside of aspx pages Global to all sessions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

Forgive me, it has been years and I am getting mixed results in my search. Using the VB code below in a traditional .NET forms application, will the value of ClientKey be global to the session or to the application domain?

```
Public Class AuthenticationClient

    Private Shared Property ClientKey As String
        Get
            Return HttpContext.Current.Session("ClientKey")
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            HttpContext.Current.Session("ClientKey") = value
        End Set
    End Property
   
  'The function below is called only once on the FormsAuth login page for each successful login attempt
   Public Shared Sub SetClientKeyForSession(clientKeyForSession As String)
       ClientKey = clientKeyForSession 
   End Sub


   'This can be called for multiple contacts
   Public Shared Async Sub SaveSomething(userId As Integer)
       Await SomeDataAccess.SaveThisAsync(userId, ClientKey) '<- Not Me.ClientKey but is it the same session value set at login, I assume yes.
   End Sub

....
End Class
```

Comment: Well, session("somevalue") is global to the user. However, what you are returning in above is NOT from session - so that's a different question, and different issue. But yes, session("some value") is global to EACH user - not application wide. As noted, the problem in your sample code, is you not at a all returning a value from session - so whatever that value or constant is - it not coming from session. But the set part of your code stub - yes, it sets a value into session. but the return value? Gee, might have to google that part since it not session

Comment: The Getter does return from user session. Sorry, it is just a fancy way of getting a value from session and if it is null returning a default value. The last time I was this deep into webforms, I did not use static methods. So, if a static property reads and writes from user session then you don't think the value will get mixed up application wide. I know static values can be global to the application, however, I would think the propery above would be contained to session :/ And SessionConst are just constant strings.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - I updated for clarity.

Comment: yes, that should work.  I would hope (suggest) that you adopt sql server based session management, since a app-pool restart (which can occur often) will re-set and blow out session() - not to mention the default 20 minute timeout. I had so many troubles over the years that i just setup the sessions to use sql server based ones. - and everything became 100% reliable.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - Yes we are storing session state in a database. Thanks for your remarks. I think the global functions would still operate within the HttpContext of session per call above for the property value. Thanks for clarification. I would mark as an answer if you posted as such, either way, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Properties* are just get and set methods. It's static *fields* that are shared by the app domain. Since you have no fields (only wrapping a session variable in get and set methods) everything is scoped to the session.

Note that *automatic* properties (e.g. `Shared Property MyString As String` in VB) actually create backing fields that you don't see. But that's not what you're doing here, so no backing field is created and no static data is used.